# How expensive it is to load the environment to run a Python script?

Tags: python, environment, overhead

I have a background python script that gets ran several thousand times a day. I'm simply running it with `python foo.py`. The script itself does some imports (a parsing library and sqlalchemy) and then makes a database connection, makes the parsing and saves the data to db.

I'm wondering if it adds a lot of overhead to load the python environment each time the script is run?

I could make it so that the script is started once and it would have a polling loop to see if it should do something, but want to clarify that it's worth to do this.

Any input?

Answer (score 4):

of course it adds a lot of overhead, and it would be (however negligibly) more eco-friendly to use a built-in poll or select(); but then you'd have to have a watchdog to see if it crashed, or use respawn from inittab. as long as the server load is fine, it might not be worth the effort.

---

forgot to mention, memory leaks that would be unnoticeable in a cron job can become server-eating monsters when your script runs as a daemon. you'd want to watch it carefully the first hour or two, to see if it's growing.

Comment: Also, the OS overhead of forking a process is has to be figured in.  A big-old polling loop is much more efficient.

Comment: Similar arguments apply for using CGI vs FCGI or WSGI. If it runs fast enough for you the difference in overhead doesn't really matter too much - although you may reduce your CO2 emissions :) If you are I/O bound it may make very little difference indeed